# How to call a controller function by using ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have two radio button and one check box..The radio buttons are all and selected when all is checked i have to load one view page and if a checkbox is checked i want to perform different action and i have to load different view page..I tried it with if and else statment but it does not give me a expected result..so i tried it with different function name..If a check box is checked i have to make a call on Receipt Reg chek()..I tried it with ajax but i did not get a call to Receipt Reg check() it still calls a Receipt Reg Check1() that is loaded on a form action..what changes have to be done on my code..Help me to solve this issue

Controller Code:

```
    public function Receipt_reg_check1()
{
    $startdate = $this->input->post('SDate');
        $enddate = $this->input->post('EDate');
        $date = str_replace('/', '-', $startdate);
        $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
        $date2 = str_replace('/', '-', $enddate);
        $newDate2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date2));
        $data['startdate'] = $startdate;
        $data['enddate'] = $enddate;
        $item=$this->input->post('item');
        if ($this->input->post('all'))
        {
        $this->db->where('date >=', $newDate);
        $this->db->where('date <=', $newDate2);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('purchasebill');
        $this->db->order_by("date", "asc");
        $this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = purchasebill.partyname','left outer');
  $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        $data['query'] = $query;
        $this->load->view('Receipt_View', $data);

}
if($this->input->post('selected'))
    {

        if($name = $this->input->post('businessType'))
        {
            $this->db->where('date >=', $newDate);
        $this->db->where('date <=', $newDate2);
        $this->db->where('PName',$name);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('purchasebill');
        $this->db->order_by("date", "asc");
        $this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = purchasebill.partyname','left outer');
        $query = $this->db->get('')->result_array();
  $data['query'] = $query;
  $this->load->view('Receipt_View', $data);

      }
}}

public function Receipt_reg_check()
{
if($this->input->post('all'))
    {
        if($this->input->post('item')){
        $startdate = $this->input->post('SDate');
        $enddate = $this->input->post('EDate');
        $date = str_replace('/', '-', $startdate);
        $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
        $date2 = str_replace('/', '-', $enddate);
        $newDate2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date2));
        $data['startdate'] = $startdate;
        $data['enddate'] = $enddate;
        $this->db->where('billdate >=', $newDate);
        $this->db->where('billdate <=', $newDate2);
        $this->db->select('vno,Prdtname,Qty,bundle');
        $this->db->from('purchaseitem');
            $this->db->order_by("vno", "asc");
            $this->db->join('itemmaster','itemmaster.itcode = purchaseitem.Product_Code','left outer');
            $query = $this->db->get('')->result_array();
            $data['query'] = $query;
            $this->db->where('date >=', $newDate);
            $this->db->where('date <=', $newDate2);
            $this->db->select();
            $this->db->from('purchasebill');
            $this->db->order_by('voucherno');
            $this->db->group_by('voucherno');
            $this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = purchasebill.partyname','left outer');
            $query = $this->db->get('')->result_array();
            $data['query1'] = $query;
            $this->load->view('Receipt_View1',$data);

    }}

    }}
```

Html Page:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?=site_url('welcome/Receipt_reg_check1')?>" method="POST" target="_blank">
        <input type="radio" class='rd'name="all" value="op1" checked=""> All
    <input type="radio" name="selected" class='rd' value="op2"> Selected
<input type="checkbox" name="item" id="AcNo" >Item description
```

Ajax Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/Receipt_reg_check",
                data:{id:$(this).val()},
                datatype:'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    $("#AcNo").val(res);

                }
            });

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: From what you write up here it seems like your form is not connected to the AJAX call.
You should connect the ajax call to a user interaction (form button click or submit) not on document ready.

Answer (score 0):

put

```
        $this->load->view('Receipt_View',$data);
```

instead of

```
        $this->load->view('Receipt_View1',$data);
```